# Swift 3: Cannot use instance member within property initializer. Initializer runs before 'self' is available

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently working on learning Swift 3 and I'm trying to implement an XML parser that parses data from a URL. I've created a separate file to handle the XML parsing and have setup it as follows.

```
 let xmlDoc  = NSURL(string: "http://labs.bible.org/api/?passage=random&type=xml")

 var parser1 = XMLParser(contentsOf: xmlDoc)
```

I'm currently having issues with syntax however. Swift is highlighting the line where I initialize the XML Parser and giving the error "Cannot use instance member 'xmlDoc' within property initializer, property initializers run before 'self' is available.

This is probably something really simple but I wasn't able to find a solution in my google searches.

Any feedback is appreciated!

-Alex

Comment: Nice that they've updated the error message – used to be a vague "Instance member X cannot be used on type Y"

Comment: You can't call 'xmlDoc' within property initializers. You can initialize 'parser1' within another method such as viewDidLoad etc